# WPF Display same image in two different windows

Tags: wpf, image, binding

I have a MainWindow with a datagrid and an image frame. The datagrid contains one image per row. When I select the row, the image (image1) is displayed in a image frame.

I want to display that image in another window (WindowPicture) by clicking on a button in MainWindow.

I have the following code working fine but when I select a different image, it is updating in the main window but not in the second window:

MainWindow XAML Image 1

```
Image x:Name="image1"
Source="{Binding SelectedImage,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource imgPathCon}}"
```

MainWindow XAML Button action

```
Name="btnWindowPicture"
Click="btnWindowPicture_Click"
```

MainWindow.cs Button action

```
private void btnWindowPicture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowPicture win2 = new WindowPicture();
        win2.image2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(SelectedImage));
        win2.Show();
    }
```

WindowPicture XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="image2" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     Height="798" 
     Margin="10,10,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="871" Stretch="Fill"  />
</Grid>
```

I probably need to create a two way binding mode in the button_click method, but I don't know how to do it programmatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the DataContext of the `Image` in the `WindowPicture` window to the same as the DataContext of the `Image` in the `MainWindow` and set up a similar binding programmatically:

```
private void btnWindowPicture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WindowPicture win2 = new WindowPicture();
    win2.image2.DataContext = image1.DataContext;
    win2.image2.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("SelectedImage") { Converter = new YourImagePathConverterType() });
    win2.Show();
}
```

Make sure that the `Image` element is accessible from outside the `WindowPicture` class for this to work. You could either set the x:Shared attribute to public or internal or expose the `Image` through a property of the WindowPicture class:

```
<Image x:Name="image2" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     Height="798" 
     Margin="10,10,0,0" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="871" Stretch="Fill"
     x:Shared="False"/>
```

Comment: Thanks mm8. I have tried to set the Datacontext of the image in XAML without success. It is working like a charm now. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have the datacontext of the WindowPicture same as the MainWindow? That way you will be able to bind image in both windows.